# ProgressDialog shows black screen

Tags: java, android, multithreading, progressdialog

I have read some related questions but they all suggest I use a handler and threads which I am using, yet I still get a black out when running this code, the progress bar cannot be seen moving and after a few seconds the screen goes black. However the process finished after that by a short while.

Code :

```
public void onRunButtonClicked(View view) throws IOException
{
    // prepare for a progress bar dialog
    progressBarStatus = 0;
    progressBar = new ProgressDialog(view.getContext());
    progressBar.setCancelable(true);
    progressBar.setMessage("Updating...");
    progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    progressBar.setProgress(0);
    progressBar.setMax(97);
    progressBar.show();

    // bulk insert books
    bulkInsertBooks(this.getApplicationContext());
}

private void bulkInsertBooks(final Context context) throws IOException
{
    // setup progressbar
    progressBar.setMax(5000);

    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            // delete existing rows
            db.execSQL("DELETE FROM Book");

            // load csv from assets
            InputStream is = null;
            try
            {
                is = context.getAssets().open("books.dat");
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            // now insert into db
            String sql = "INSERT INTO Book VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);";
            SQLiteStatement statement = db.compileStatement(sql);
            db.beginTransaction();

            String line;
            try
            {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    String[] RowData = line.split("\\|");
                    statement.clearBindings();
                    statement.bindString(1, RowData[0]);
                    statement.bindString(2, RowData[1]);
                    statement.bindString(3, RowData[2]);
                    statement.bindString(4, RowData[3]);
                    statement.bindString(5, RowData[4]);
                    statement.bindString(6, RowData[5]);
                    statement.execute();

                    // Update the progress bar in every iteration
                    progressBarHandler.post(new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            progressBar.setProgress(progressBarStatus++);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // finish
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            db.endTransaction();
            if (is != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    is.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: I just answered something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19881821/cant-get-spinning-progress-bar-to-work/19881901#19881901 I would strongly suggest an AsyncTask for this.

Comment: @Blacklight Took some work but I implemented AsyncTask and it now works great :) many thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped. If you don't mind you can upvote my other answer as an indication that it will probably solve that question as well.